# json_encode doesn't double quote NULL ; cocoa touch mishandles

Tags: php, sql, objective-c, json, cocoa

I'm writing a native iOS 7 app that requires retrieving data from a JSON api (that I control). Example JSON output looks like:

```
{
"id" : "544",
"name" : "1900 Green Gables",
"address" : "83 West Main Street",
"city" : "Milford",
"phone" : "(607) 547-1381",
"video_thumb" : null,
"thumbnail" : null,
"s_description" : null
}
```

I'm using php's `json_encode()` to convert the associative array returned from my DB query. In the objective-c I use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert the JSON into an `NSMutableArray`. The problem is that `null` values are converted to `"<null>"`. I suspect this is because `json_encode()` is not double quoting `null` values. I'd rather keep the value `null` for consistency's sake (doesn't seem robust to check if a value is `"<null>"` in my obj-c code)

I know that I could fix the problem by regexing the output of `json_encode()`, but I'd rather avoid the extra step and I'm worried about the negative impact on performance. Are there any changes I can make to the PHP, Objective-C or even the SQL query to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<null>` is the stringified description of `[NSNull null]`, which is a placeholder for `nil` in Cocoa collections (which can't contain `nil` directly).

You should be comparing the value to `[NSNull null]`:

```
if (dictFromJson[@"video_thumb"] != [NSNull null]) {
    // do stuff with video thumb here
}
```

Comment: Very cool, did not know that. Tested it out and it takes care of everything, thanks a lot!